# How to add header location properly with something more?

Tags: php, mysql, header

```
<?php session_start(); 
ob_start(); 
include("config.php");
$user=$_POST['fname'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_detail WHERE password='$pass' AND email='$user'") or   die("Couldn't query the user-database.");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if(!$result)
{
die(mysql_error());
}
 $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) 
{   
$_SESSION['login_user']=$user;
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
}
else if($pass=="" || $user=="") 
{
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
}
else
{
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 

}


?>
```

Here if any user is not giving username or password, it's redirecting to the previous page according to the code..

But i want to add something in the header location like this

```
header('location:index.php?msg=incorect1');
```

How can i add this in the code

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: dont use mysql_* ,they are depraceted and your code is open to sql injection too.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?msg=incorect1");
```

note: this only works if the referring page is not using the GET already.

Alternatively, you can set a $_SESSION variable which is read by the page. This does however require you to use sessions throughout the site, wherever you offer the login option.

Answer (score 0):

Set session for messages.either success or errors like this :

```
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Sorry some error";
or
$_SESSION['msg'] = "Successfully saved";
```

Then use redirect like you did.

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

And on the previous page just `echo  $_SESSION['msg'];`